# electric field in hollow conductor

Tags: electrostatics

when we have a hollow conductor and we charge it then the quantity of charges and electric  on and in inner surface of conductor material  is zero and this is okay .But is the electric field also zero inside the air cavity and why?(suppose that there is no charge in the air cavity and that the conductor is initially neutral and we charge it with total charge Q)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the electric field will be zero inside the cavity. The explanation is given on the following page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage